# generating function small question about coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

generating function of a0+a1... C((n+4),4)

can anyone help?

small step in proof

thank you so much

please show steps

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.





Take a look here to know how to write in LATEX. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Your question is too unclear. What you try to ask number of combinations to choose 4 element from set of $n+4$ elements. It doesn't even require generating function.

Generating functions are applied usually when you need to choose $n$ elements from $k$ sets. Also it's best to learn generating function using examples, so it would be wise to think of a problem and post here.

Comment: Are you asking for a closed form for
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{4}x^n=\frac1{(1-x)^5}
$$
?

Answer (score 2):

If what you are seeking is a closed form for
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{4}x^n\tag{1}
$$
then consider [negative binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_negative_integers). $(1)$ becomes
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{4}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{n+4}{n}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-5}{n}(-1)^nx^n\\[6pt]
&=(1-x)^{-5}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$